# Should I set a mysql root password?

Tags: mysql, security

I have a webserver hosted on AWS, with the security group allowing access from all IP address's to TCP port 22 (ssh) and 443 (https). ssh access requires a user to have my private key.

Should the root user on the MySQL database on this server have a password? If so, why? The only way to log into the database is by ssh'ing into the machine, and if a hacker can do that  then they can easily look at the data anyway by examining the .myd files.

However, the common wisdom I've come across seems to advocate for restricting root access to the database.

**Update**
What if my database is on a different machine than the webserver, and the database can only be accessed over the mysql port by the webserver? Is it still recommended to have a root password then?

Comment: Any feedback on the negative vote? Its a pretty specific and clearly stated question.

Comment: First I drop some 0-day malware on your computer, harvest all your private keys and browser saved passwords, then I own everything you have access to. And I can always run MySQL through an ssh tunnel...

Comment: You're saying you can run MySQL through an ssh tunnel, without having my private key? Or is that assuming you obtained my private key?

Comment: +1 from me to even it out. You probably received the downvote because any System Admin seriously suggesting doing this would be whacked upside the head with the Clue Stick. Occasionally SFers forget that just because something is a terrible idea it's not a terrible question (mostly because we have been seeing a lot of both recently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should use a password. Why? Because multiple layers of security is better then a single layer of security, known as the 'walled garden' approach. If someone breeches that wall you're going to wish you had multiple layers of security to keep them out.

3. Why would you not want to set a password? Passwords are inconvenient, but the inconvenience is minor. You might consider placing the password into ~root/.my.cnf and make sure the file permissions are very strict. For example:

   ```
   [client]
   password=hackme123##
   ```
4. Bugs happen. Both https and ssh are reasonably secure, but exploits exist which could allow someone to steal your https session or sniff data from your https session.
5. Some users use unencrypted ssh keys-- that is, a SSH key which was created without a passprase. If a hacker was able to steal your private key they could use the key to log into your database host (Since a passphrase is not required), and then log into the database itself.
6. https is only as secure as the web application which runs within it. It's not unheard of for a web application to accidentally allow commandline access due to poor coding.
7. If someone hacked your web application, they could log into the database as root and delete all databases, insert links to porn and malware sites in your precious CMS, create backdoor accounts for their own use, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's not the only way to get in. Is your web application perfectly secure? (The correct answer is always "No.") So yes, you do have a channel by which someone can get in, and it's the actual web service you're running.

If someone gets in, by default they can't look at the .myd files. You'd have to have a root shell exploit in order to access the files directly. If someone somehow "gets in" with an unprivileged account (like your web server user, for example), then the MySQL root password is the only barrier preventing them from completely exfiltrating or destroying your data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should set the root password on your MySQL database and then keep it in a secure and recoverable escrow facility.

There's no "checklist" for security, security is a process and a mindset but there are a few core principles one of which is defense in depth:

[Defense in Depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_%28computing%29) - Never put your eggs in a single basket.

Authentication - Passwords are a "what you know" authentication token. Problem: a default password (in this case a blank one) is known by everyone. Therefore you no longer have an authentication mechanism for your database.

Summary: Setting a password "costs" you very little and makes the attacker's job significantly harder. It's a good buy.